# Multiple logins to windows server in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, authorization, windows-server

I just want to know whether there is a way to login windows server (OS Process Sampler) in the same test plan as we can do for Unix servers (SSH command).

In SSH command it is asking for username and password to login the UNIX box, but it is not there in OS Process sampler.

I just want to check logs in different Windows Server but I need to have only one `.jmx` file. This will be a central one and it should not be installed in any of the Windows Server where I check logs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. I tried it with dos command itself it worked.I used net command and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

[Microsoft Powershell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/mt173057.aspx) has ability of executing remote commands, you just need to enable this mode, see [Enable and Use Remote Commands in Windows PowerShell](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff700227.aspx) for details.

Once done you should be able to execute commands on remote Windows machines like:

```
powershell.exe $password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String YOUR_PASSWORD -AsPlainText -Force; $credentials = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist "YOUR_USERNAME",$password; Invoke-Command -Computer REMOTE_MACHINE -cred $credentials -scriptBlock {YOUR_COMMAND}
```

Replace:

- `YOUR_USERNAME` with Windows username
- `YOUR_PASSWORD` with Windows password
- `REMOTE_MACHINE` with hostname or IP address of the remote machine
- `YOUR_COMMAND` with Powershell script you want to execute

More information: [How to Run External Commands and Programs Locally and Remotely from JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter)